# IdlError: Type not found for custom struct

Tags: anchor, cpi, anchor-test, idl

I got started with writing smart contracts 2 days ago so please bear with me. The function `emit_event` emits an event. I want to call the function via a CPI form another program. I have written code for the CPI as well. When I do `anchor test`, I'm getting the error
`IdlError: Type not found: {"name":"revent","type":{"defined":"RoosterEvent"}}`

I checked the generated IDL and it has the `revent` type is present in there.

Following is my code for `logger/lib.rs`. This has the exposed function.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};

declare_id!("ENdMF5CR3qvWj2L6xZWofrYiYaQVV3dM94ghtbrvJ9QN");

#[program]
pub mod logger {
    use super::*;

    pub fn emit_event(_ctx: Context<SetRoosterEvent>, data: String, label: String) -> Result<()> {

        let m_data = data;
        let m_label = label;

        emit!(RoosterEvent {
            data: m_data.to_string(),
            label: m_label.to_string(),
        });

        msg!("HAHA");
        msg!(m_data.as_str());
        msg!(m_label.as_str());
        msg!("HAHA");
        
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts, AnchorDeserialize, AnchorSerialize)]
pub struct SetRoosterEvent<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub event: Account<'info, TestEvent>,
}

#[account]
pub struct TestEvent {
    pub revent: RoosterEvent,
}

#[event]
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Default)]
pub struct RoosterEvent {
    pub data: String,
    pub label: String,
}
```

Following is my `consumer/lib.rs` that does the CPI call

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use logger::cpi::accounts::SetRoosterEvent;
use logger::program::Logger;
use logger::{self, TestEvent};

declare_id!("5M8M5VCtD3cDkqJJj3NmfgVwnrVj1t9NSpmdSB3XGKR6");

#[program]
pub mod consumer {
    use super::*;

    pub fn do_something(ctx: Context<DoSomething>) -> Result<()> {
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.logger_program.to_account_info().clone();
        let cpi_accounts = SetRoosterEvent {
            event: ctx.accounts.event.to_account_info().clone(),
        };
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        logger::cpi::emit_event(cpi_ctx, "data".to_string(), "label".to_string())?;
        Ok(())
    }

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DoSomething<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub event: Account<'info, TestEvent>,
    pub logger_program: Program<'info, Logger>,
}
```

Following is my test file

```
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Logger } from "../target/types/logger";
import { Consumer } from "../target/types/consumer";

describe("logger", () => {
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);



  const program = anchor.workspace.Logger as Program<Logger>;
  const consumer = anchor.workspace.Consumer as Program<Consumer>;
  


  it("Does CPI", async()=>{

    await consumer.methods.doSomething().rpc();
    

  })

});
```

Edit: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/WilfredAlmeida/93cb327e55dbe6aff1fa05b416cb5961) of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing an `event` (`RoosterEvent`) to be held in an `account` (`TestEvent`). It seems that Anchor doesn't cover this corner case, because in the IDL `RoosterEvent` is defined in `events` but Anchor is looking for it in `types` within the IDL.

If you simply remove the `#[event]` macro attribute from `RoosterEvent` this error will be gone.

So to fix this, simply don't store an `event` (in this case `RoosterEvent`) in an `account`. Instantiate your `event` only in the code where you're actually `emit!`ing it, and pass the data you need to log in a different struct that is not an `event`.

Comment: I changed the 

`TestEvent` to ```#[account]
pub struct TestEvent {pub ignore: u64,}``` 

and still the same error 

`IdlError: Type not found: {"name":"event","type":{"defined":"Account<'info,TestEvent>"}}`

Comment: `RoosterEvent` now only has `#[event]` and is only used in the `emit!`

Comment: Add a link with the code, on https://gist.github.com/ for example

Comment: Here's the gist

https://gist.github.com/WilfredAlmeida/93cb327e55dbe6aff1fa05b416cb5961

Comment: lib.rs is a ts file and SetRoosterEvent and RoosterEvent are missing

Comment: I've updated the gist. Sorry for the mistake. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida This new error is a different issue from the one originally described. To fix the new error, remove `derive` of `AnchorDeserialize`, `AnchorSerialize` from `SetRoosterEvent`

Comment: Now I'm getting error `Error: AnchorError caused by account: event. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.`